# Lamda function calling API Gateway endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm new to aws and trying out some setup.
I have this design on the same vpc:

```
API Gateway1-> /gateway-> Lambda python script1-> send request to API Gateway2 endpoint /downstream 

API Gateway1-> /downstream-> Lambda python script2 return status

API Gateway2-> /downstream-> Lambda python script3 return status
```

what I have found strange with this setup is that the "Lambda python script1" is sending request  to "API Gateway1 endpoint /downstream" when it has reference to "API Gateway2 endpoint /downstream".

here's an example of the Lambda python script1:

```
import json
import urllib3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  headers=event["headers"]
  headers=event["body"]
  url = "https://{apiGatewayID}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/prod/downstream"
  http = urllib3.PoolManager()
  r = http.request('POST', url, body=payload,headers=headers)
  response = {"statusCode": r.status}
  return response
```

Any idea what could cause this to happen?

Comment: The problem is in your code or your configuration. AWS does not simply decide to wrong the call api gateway.

Comment: if you've defined a DNS entry for it (custom domain) and they are the same, then its going with the more recent one. Othewise, you are likely using the wrong endpoint. Try changing the /downstream to something else and see if you can hit it or if you get a does not exist error.

Comment: I've add my sample code.  The url is definitly set to reference api Gateway 2 ID

Comment: Did you log `url` to verify it's the correct API Gateway? Did you invoke this URL outside of your Lambda to see what it invokes?

Comment: Yep.  using the url outside works.